# ASP.NET How to send Eval("") to javascript method for manipulating its value

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have the following code which is working fine

```
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div runat="server" id="divFileName" class="divFileName" title='<%# Eval("FileName")%>'>
                <%# Eval("FileName")%></div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

the result of `Eval("FileName")` returns a full path string such as the following:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\sbs_diasymreader.dll

I would like in the client side to send `Eval("FileName");` to a javascript method that will crop `Eval("FileName");` value and will return the file name only without the full path. (for this example it should return `sbs_diasymreader.dll`)

The result of what i am trying to achieve is that eventually the table that currently contains full names with path, will display only the file without the path

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the **FileName** field contains the full path you can use [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) class

```
<%# new FileInfo((string)Eval("FileName")).Name %>
```

Answer (score 0):

That expression is processed server side and you cannot have the returned value of your javascript displayed in the grid, you'll just have the function call. Do this instead

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="File Name">
<ItemTemplate>
   <%# System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Eval("FileName").ToString()) %>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

In VB.NET you can use the following or as Adrian Iftode mentioned.

```
<%# FileIO.FileSystem.GetName(Eval("FileName").ToString()) %>
```

Alternatively you can use your code and write jQuery to go through each span (update your selector accordingly) as follows:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("span").each(function () {
                $(this).text(getFileName($(this).text()));
            });
        });

        function getFileName(filePath) {
            var index = filePath.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1;
            return filePath.substring(index, filePath.length);
        }
    </script>
```